# Sorting a PFQuery by counting objects in array

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sorting, parse-platform, pfquery

What I am doing is in my Parse query, I check to see which posts have been check marked (liked) in the last 7 days. I then remove the dates of those that haven't. This is working fine. Now my problem is that I need to sort them in my UITableView in descending order of how many dates are in the array but my sortedArrayUsingComparator isn't working. Im new to Objective C so its probably something easy but idk. Here's my code

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForParse {
PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

//[query1 selectKeys: [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[ NSString @"checkMark"]]];

[query1 whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:[LocationController sharedSingleton].locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:[LocationController sharedSingleton].locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude] withinMiles:50];
[query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error){

        placesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

        NSMutableArray *toDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

        for (PFObject *tempObject in placesArray){
            checkDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tempObject objectForKey:@"checkMarkDates"]];
            for (NSString *dateString in checkDates) {
                NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString: dateString];
                if ([date timeIntervalSinceNow] > -604800){
                    [toDelete addObject:dateString];
                }
            }
            [checkDates removeObjectsInArray:toDelete];
            [tempObject removeObjectsInArray:checkDates forKey:@"checkMarkDates"];

            sortedArray = [placesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                NSUInteger *first = [[obj1 objectForKey:@"checkMarkDates"] count];
                NSNumber *f = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:first];
                NSUInteger *second = [[obj2 objectForKey:@"checkMarkDates"] count];
                NSNumber *s = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:second];

                return [f compare:s];
            }];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
    }
    [placesTable reloadData];
}];
return query1;
```

}

Comment: What isn't working, the sort isn't working? Have you verified that `placesArray` contains the values you would expect, before passing it into the sort function?

Comment: Yes the sort isn't working. And yeah placesArray contains the right values

Comment: Ok, assuming that placesArray contains the correct value, I can't see why the sort is failing. My next test would be to manually create an array of 3 items, set a break point at the end of the comparison block, and use pen and paper to determine why the sort isn't resolving properly.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use breakpoints but I just read on the parse website that using [query1 whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:] will sort by nearest to farthest. Could that be the problem? and if so can I override this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had the sortedArrayUsingComparator in the for statement. I moved it out and it works fine now.